# How do i Get value of selected radio button in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

i am trying to get a value of the selected radio button but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
<input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star1" ng-model="star" ng-value="'5'"/>

<label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>

<input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star1" ng-model="star" ng-value="'4'"/>

<label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>

<input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star1" ng-model="star" ng-value="'3'"/>

<label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>

<input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star1" ng-model="star" ng-value="'2'"/>

<label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>

<input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star1" ng-model="star" ng-value="'1'"/>

<label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
<div>{{start}}</div>
```

Could you guys please help me out?I am not checking where the error is.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the value of the checked radio button when submitting a form using angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166270/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-checked-radio-button-when-submitting-a-form-using)

Comment: It should be star <div>{{star}}</div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of selected radio button in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450288/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its typo start remove t in these code

`<div>{{star}}</div>`
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12808/)

Comment: removing 't' makes things worse. i cannot even click the stars anymore

Comment: I posted the working fiddle just go through and come back with your issues

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is as below

```
 <input class="star star-3" type="radio" name="response" data-ng-model="star" data-ng-value="true"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```
<div>{{star}}</div>
```

And here is the plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/JAbsgMOoagjn535fh8qE?p=preview